# Why aren't these Ember.js view events being fired?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to do something when my view becomes visible, but the `becameVisible` event callback isn't being called.

Here is my view:

```
App.LessonView = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function() {
        console.log("click");
    },

    becameVisible: function() {
        console.log("becameVisible");
    },

    willClearRender: function() {
        console.log("willClearRender");
    }
});
```

When I click any element in the view, the `click` event is fired, but `becameVisible` and `willClearRender` aren't ever fired.

Is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: What is your ember version?

Comment: You want to use didInsertElement http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.LinkView.html#event_didInsertElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

didInsertElement fires when Ember is putting the views dom into the page. 
willDestroyElement will fire when ember is removing the dom from the page.

```
App.LessonView = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function() {
        console.log("click");
    },

    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log("didInsertElement");
    },

    willDestroyElement: function() {
        console.log("willDestroyElement");
    }
});
```

A few things you should be aware of when using didInsertElement
1. When the model that backs the view is changed ember will update the bindings in the current view so Ember doesn't have to reinsert the view and `didInsertElement` will not fire.
2. If you setup event handlers on `didInsertElement` like a bootstrap menu event you need to turn that binding off in the `willDestroyElement` event.

Answer (score 1):

`willClearRender` is called before the view is rerendered. `becameVisible` is called when the isVisible property of the view changes to true. You check out this [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vihozubi/8/edit).